# Restricting Google Map API to show only Cities, States & Country

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I am new to Google Map APIs.. I wish to use dropdown where user will type location and correspondingly google will give suggestions..
but problem is i dont want Google to give Street & District names..I want only City, State & country names to be autosuggested..My code is as follows

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
    <script>
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

How to get only City & Country name from the API ?
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 4):

Add 'regions' to the options in the constructor:

```
var acOptions = {
        types: ['(regions)']
    };

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], acOptions);
```

Comment: i tried this too..But its not working.. It still gives me all, for eg, locality, city, state and country..i just want google to search for city, country or state..and not localities inside city

Comment: @JigarJain Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

In case someone needs a current answer:

Add **types=(cities)** in your Google Maps API call, like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&types=(cities)&language=en-AU"></script>
```

Check the "Place Types" section in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types) for more information.